# How to create array of functions from command line in bash?

Tags: bash

I have functions in my bash file:

```
function fn1 {
  echo "fn1 commands"
}

function fn2 {
  echo "fn2 commands"
}

function fn3 {
  echo "fn3 commands"
}
```

and I have array of functions - the bash execute function in the array:

```
funcs_to_test=( fn1 fn2 fn3 )

for testP in "${funcs_to_test[@]}"
do
    $testP
done
```

One more thing I need to do is to execute a function or functions by the command line input:

```
bash app.sh -f fn1 fn2
```

So I read the input like this:

```
while [[ "$#" -gt 0 ]]; do case $1 in
  -f|--fn) fns="$2"; shift;;
  *) echo "Unknown parameter passed: $1"; exit 1;;
esac; shift; done
```

and I want to set the value of `fns` to `funcs_to_test` if not empty:

```
if [ -z "$fns" ] then
  funcs_to_test=($fns)
fi
```

but I get an error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
```

How to make execute these functions from the command line?

```
#!/bin/bash

function fn1 {
  echo "fn1 commands"
}

function fn2 {
  echo "fn2 commands"
}

function fn3 {
  echo "fn3 commands"
}
while [[ "$#" -gt 0 ]]; do case $1 in
  -f|--fsn) fns="$2"; shift;;
  *) echo "Unknown parameter passed: $1"; exit 1;;
esac; shift; done

funcs_to_test=( fn1 fn2 fn3 )

if [ -z "$fns" ] then
  funcs_to_test=($fns)      <--- here the problem. I do it wrong?
fi

for testP in "${funcs_to_test[@]}"
do
  $testP
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if [ -z "$fns" ]; then
#               ^
```

Add a semicolon, or put the `then` on a separate line.

You can use [ShellCheck](https://shellcheck.net) to catch many such syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this script that includes some syntax fixes and other suggested fixes:

```
function fn1 {
  echo "fn1 commands"
}

function fn2 {
  echo "fn2 commands"
}

function fn3 {
  echo "fn3 commands"
}

funcs_to_test=(fn1 fn2 fn3)

if (($# > 0)); then
   case $1 in
      -f|--fns) shift; funcs_to_test=("$@");;
      *) echo "Unknown parameter passed: $1"; exit 1;;
   esac;
fi

#declare -p funcs_to_test

for testP in "${funcs_to_test[@]}"; do
   printf '%s: ' 'executing'
   "$testP"
done
```

Comment: It would be good if you could explain the changes and fixes you've made.

Comment: Possibly add: `IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra unk_funcs < <(LC_MESSAGES=C; declare -pF "${funcs_to_test[@]}" 2>&1 >/dev/null | cut -d ':' -f3); if [ "${#unk_funcs[@]}" -gt 0 ]; then { echo "Unknown functions:" ${unk_funcs[@]}; } 2>&1; fi`